# How to change namespace in the middle of document using XSLT crosswalk

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create a XML document that will have a set of other XML documents inside. It basically should looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OAI-PMH 
  xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">    

  <ListRecords>
    <record>
        <metadata>
            <registryObjects 
              xmlns="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects http://services.ands.org.au/documentation/rifcs/schema/registryObjects.xsd">

             <registryObject> 
             ...
             </registryObject>
           </registryObjects>
         </metadata>
       </record>
     </ListRecords>
   </OAI-PMH>
```

I have find out that I can alter namespace by using xsl:element:

```
<xsl:element name="registryObjects" namespace="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects">
```

However, it only changed namespace for this particular element. The next one has become "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" again:

```
<metadata>
    <registryObjects xmlns="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects http://services.ands.org.au/documentation/rifcs/schema/registryObjects.xsd">
      <registryObject xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" group="NII">
```

My code looks like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="oai:record">
    <record>
       <xsl:element name="registryObjects" namespace="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects">
       <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">
        <xsl:text>http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects http://services.ands.org.au/documentation/rifcs/schema/registryObjects.xsd</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
         <registryObject>
```

etc.

Is it possible to change namespace for all elements after `registryObjects`?

Comment: Please show your XSLT code and the XML ouput you expect. Thanks. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @MathiasMüller The XSLT are in the github: https://github.com/rd-switchboard/Toolbox/blob/master/XSLT/NII_to_RIFCS/nii_researcher_rifcs.xsl The sample input and outputs are in the same git folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
<xsl:element name="registryObjects" namespace="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects">
```

you are placing `registryObjects` in the designated namespace - but you are not changing the *default namespace*.

Therefore, the descendant elements (`registryObject` in your example) inherit the *default namespace* currently *in scope* - which according to your result, happens to be `"http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"` (you haven't showed us the complete stylesheet).

The simple solution here is to use a *literal result element*. Instead of:

```
<xsl:element name="registryObjects" namespace="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects">
       <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">
        <xsl:text>http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects http://services.ands.org.au/documentation/rifcs/schema/registryObjects.xsd</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
         <registryObject>
```

do:

```
<registryObjects xmlns="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects http://services.ands.org.au/documentation/rifcs/schema/registryObjects.xsd">
    <registryObject>
```

This not only places `registryObjects` in the designated namespace, but also changes the *default namespace*, so that `registryObject` will inherit it.

Without changing the *default namespace*, you would have to place `registryObject` in the designated namespace **explicitly**, for example:

```
<registryObject xmlns="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects">
```

or:

```
<xsl:element name="registryObject" namespace="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects">
```

---

It is probably worth noting that in the expected result document you have shown us, **all** elements are in the `"http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"` namespace (established as default by the root `OAI-PMH` element) - **except** `registryObjects` and `registryObject`, that live in their own `"http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects"` namespace (established as default by the `registryObjects` element).

Comment: yep, that was exactly what I needed.